# Удаление всего до первой запятой

Tags: php

Хочу сделать метки, как на хэшкоде http://yadi.sk/d/LhByE1pPMPQ3o. Т.е. вводим букву - нам выдает список. Но у меня вот какая проблема. Первую метку выведу без проблем, а вторую не могу, т.к. у меня берется все значение поля. 
Т.е. по сути на keypress надо назначить такой код:
Переменной tag присвоить значение value инпута tags, но перед этим **удалить все до первой запятой** (осталось перевести в код)
Вот собственно самая сложность в удалении всего до первой запятой. Подскажите плз

Comment: Один из вариантов использовать explode(',',$tag) http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

js - string.split(',')

Comment: Думаю, что наивный метод окажется и самым быстрым.

    // $tags = 'tag, gat, gattag';
    $pos = strpos($tags, ',');
    $firstTag = substr($tags, 0, $pos);
    // var_dump($firstTag);
    // string(3) "tag"

Answer (score 1):

ответ из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/312578/#comment312580_312578):

Думаю, что наивный метод окажется и самым быстрым.

```
$tags = 'tag, gat, gattag';
$pos = strpos($tags, ',');
$firstTag = substr($tags, 0, $pos);
var_dump($firstTag);
string(3) "tag"
```

Answer (score 0):

я конечно извиняюсь, но вопрос был **удалить все до первой запятой**, и я его, в переводе на предложенный код, понял буквально:

```
$tags = 'tag, gat, gattag';
$pos = strpos($tags, ',');
$noFirstTag = trim(substr($tags, $pos+1)); // вырезаем первый тэг и запятую тоже
var_dump($noFirstTag);
```

Comment: Перед кем или за что Вы извиняетесь?

Answer (score 0):

И еще вариант...

```
$tags = 'tag, gat, gattag';
preg_match("~^.+?,\\s*(.+)~ui",$tags,$noFirstTag);
$noFirstTag=$noFirstTag[1];
var_dump($noFirstTag);
```